# PyQgis: How do I change point layer color in red AND blue with ruled based expression?

Tags: pyqgis

I want to change the color of my point layer with the ruled based option so that I create blue
and red dots based on an expression. Now I get only blue dots. How do I create 2 renderers with
a ruled based color?

```
    layer = iface.activeLayer()

# define some rules: label, expression, color name, (min scale, max scale)
road_rules = (
    ('rood', "kleur = 'red'", 'red', None),
    ('blauw', "kleur" 'blue', 'blue', None)
    
)

# create a new rule-based renderer
symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
renderer = QgsRuleBasedRenderer(symbol)

# get the "root" rule
root_rule = renderer.rootRule()

for label, expression, color_name, scale in road_rules:
    # create a clone (i.e. a copy) of the default rule
    rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone()
    # set the label, expression and color
    rule.setLabel(label)
    rule.setFilterExpression(expression)
    rule.symbol().setColor(QColor(color_name))
    # set the scale limits if they have been specified
    if scale is not None:
        rule.setScaleMinDenom(scale[0])
        rule.setScaleMaxDenom(scale[1])
    # append the rule to the list of rules
    root_rule.appendChild(rule)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most of the way there- you have some inconsistent syntax in your rule expressions, and are missing a few lines at the end of your script which removes the original child legend node, sets the renderer to the layer and repaints the layer.

Also the `setScaleMinDenom()` and `setScaleMaxDenom()` methods of `QgsRuleBasedRenderer.Rule` class have changed to:

`setMinimumScale()` and `setMaximumScale()`.

Try this slightly modified version of your script:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# define some rules: label, expression, color name, (min scale, max scale)
road_rules = (
    ('rood', "kleur LIKE 'red'", 'red', None),
    ('blauw', "kleur LIKE 'blue'", 'blue', None)
    
)

# create a new rule-based renderer
symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
renderer = QgsRuleBasedRenderer(symbol)

# get the "root" rule
root_rule = renderer.rootRule()

for label, expression, color_name, scale in road_rules:
    # create a clone (i.e. a copy) of the default rule
    rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone()
    # set the label, expression and color
    rule.setLabel(label)
    rule.setFilterExpression(expression)
    rule.symbol().setColor(QColor(color_name))
    # set the scale limits if they have been specified
    if scale is not None:
        rule.setMinimumScale(scale[0])
        rule.setMaximumScale(scale[1])
    # append the rule to the list of rules
    root_rule.appendChild(rule)

root_rule.removeChildAt(0)
layer.setRenderer(renderer)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Results on a test point layer:

[image]